# UserNotFoundException was not thrown by spring security in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on spring boot app with spring security enabled. I am using custom jdbc authentication for the same. In my user detail service impl i am throwing usernamenotfound exception but it is not getting logged anywhere. I am not seeing anything on console either.

Below is my UserDetailService impl

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ApplicationUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService{

    private ApplicationUserDao applicationUserDao;
    
    @Autowired
    public ApplicationUserDetailService(@Qualifier("db") ApplicationUserDao applicationUserDao) {
        this.applicationUserDao=applicationUserDao;
    }
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return applicationUserDao.loadUserByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(()->{
                    System.out.println("here...");
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("dsdsds");
                });
        }

}
```

Below is security configuration for jdbc auth

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider provider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider pr=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    pr.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserDetailService);
    pr.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
    return pr;
}
```

UserDetailDaoImpl

```
import java.util.Optional;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("db")
public class DBUserDaoImpl implements ApplicationUserDao{
    
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    public DBUserDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<ApplicationUser> loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(jdbcTemplate.query("select * from users where username='"+username+"'"
                ,new UserExtractor(jdbcTemplate)));
    }

}
```

When i am sending wrong details i should get exception but it is not coming. Please help me.Spring boot 2.4.2

Comment: `i should get exception but it is not coming` then what is coming? question should be updated with current behaviour and debug logs.

Comment: hi @Toerktumlare, i am getting nothing in console. Only getting dispatcher servlet request completed.
logs----
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms

Comment: please post your full debug server logs.

Comment: 1. Your query is dangerous, 2. why the template in the `UserExtractor`? 3. What does the `UserExtractor` do exactly?

Comment: UserExtractor mapping the result of result set to UserDetails class impl. jdbc template is passed because in user extractor if we found the user then i am getting the roles for user and then building the application user for authentication.

Comment: git repo url---
https://github.com/sahilkamboj334/spring-custom-jdbc-auth

Answer (score -1):

`UsernameNotFoundException` is not typically something that someone running a server really needs to know about, so Spring Security does not print a message for it. It's an error that is the fault of the user (they entered an account that doesn't exist).

Regardless, if you'd like to print the message out, you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return applicationUserDao.loadUserByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> {
        // Create an exception, but don't throw it yet
        var exception = new UsernameNotFoundException("No account found with name " + username);
        // Print the exception
        exception.printStackTrace();
        // Return the exception (throwing works too, but everything I can find says to return it)
        return exception;
    });
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't worked. Repo url -https://github.com/sahilkamboj334/spring-custom-jdbc-auth

Comment: @Sahil your repo only contains a README. If you're printing the stack trace and nothing is happening, your code probably isn't being called.

Comment: code is under master branch. now github creates main branch by default do not know why. Code is under master branch.